# Is it safe to use Spring specification predicate this way?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have this code:

```
private static Specification<Entity> caseInsensitiveLike(SingularAttribute<Entity, String> field, String searchParameter) {
        return (root, query, cb) -> {
            Predicate predicate = null;
            if (searchParameter != null) {
                predicate = cb.like(
                        cb.upper(root.get(field)),
                        "%" + searchParameter.toUpperCase() + "%");
            }
            query.orderBy(cb.desc(root.get(ExternalPatientEntity_.dateCreated)));
            return predicate;
        };
    }
```

Do I get it right that there are simply putting uncontrolled client provided input in built query or this is set as parameter to jdbc statement?